# Wordpress search box with options for post/page or everything?

Tags: wordpress, search

I am creating a Wordpress site that uses posts to handle the 'blog' side of the site and uses pages to handle the 'site' part.

I really want one search box in the header that allows people (using radio buttons I'd imagine) to select whether they are searching the 'site, 'blog' or everything.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search" />
    <select name="post_type">
        <option value="post">Blog</option>
        <option value="page">Pages</option>
        <option value="any">All</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>`
```

This should allow users to select what type of search they want to perform.  You can query using multiple parameters, this case being 'post_type' and 's' - 'post_type' can refer to posts, pages, custom post types, or any, and 's' is the string to search for in these posts.

Obviously, you can also use radio buttons named 'post_type' and valued to certain post types to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Wow, that is actually quite simple. I was overcomplicating it somewhat!!! Thank you. This works perfectly!